# MySQL TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, nodes

Trying to connect to MySQL database using node but I keep getting this error below.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

I believe I already all the modules and dependencies required.

MySQL connection:

```
var pool = mysql.createConnection;
var pool = mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host     : 'host',
    user     : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'dbname'
});
```

The error stems from the line starting ***mysql.pool.query:***

```
app.post('/', function(request, response, mysql) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        mysql.pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('/Login_Page_V2');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
        });
```

I've already tried a different code but this one results in error "length" undefined.

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? ...
```

I've spent hours trying to get it to work but I am really stuck and I could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

`pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts ...` is effectively the proper way.

The error: "length undefined" comes from this condition `results.length > 0`.

Your IF statement should look like this:

`results && results.length >= 0`

That way you'll be sure that there is a results (and so an element as well) and that it's length is greater than 0.

Comment: Will `results` ever not be an array if there's no error? I'm not familiar with this API but I'm inclined to say results should be assumed to be an array, there just needs to be some sort of `if (err) throw err` error handling at the beginning so we never get to `result` if something else went wrong.

Comment: It is common practice to check your types (either number, decimal, array, etc.), no matter how sure you think results will always return an array.
Regarding error handling, you can effectively just do `if (err) throw err`.
I personnally prefer using [async/await](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-express/) with ExpressJs, but that's another subject :P

Comment: I tried the 
`results && results.length >= 0`
but now it always results in incorrect username and password.